# Powershell referencing a returned data

Tags: powershell, object

I am running a powershell command which returns the following data:

```
InfoType                      Key                           SubKey                        Value
--------                      ---                           ------                        -----
Replication                   repl_backlog_first_byte_of...                               7602479450000
Replication                   repl_backlog_histlen                                        1048576
CPU                           used_cpu_sys                                                309301.44
CPU                           used_cpu_user                                               135181.55
CPU                           used_cpu_sys_children                                       0.05
CPU                           used_cpu_user_children                                      0.33
Keyspace                      db0                           keys                          302094
Keyspace                      db0                           expires                       302093
Keyspace                      db0                           avg_ttl                       7335993
```

I want to reference the InfoType keyspace, Key db0, Subkey keys, and the Value (302094).

I'm using the following code:

```
(Get-RedisInfo -InfoType Keyspace | where {$_.Key -eq "db0"}).Value
```

Which returns too much data:

```
(keys, 302094) (expires, 304073) (avg_ttl, 7369417)
```

I only want the 302094 number. How can I reference just the keys value?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: `Get-RedisInfo -InfoType Keyspace | Where-Object { ($_.Key -eq "db0") -and ($_.Value -eq 302094) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"`. But this makes little sense. If you already know what the value is, why run the pipeline at all?

Comment: The value changes each time the Get-RedisInfo command runs :) So -and ($_.Value -eq 302094) isn't going to work :)

Comment: Then `Get-RedisInfo -InfoType Keyspace | Where-Object { ($_.Key -eq 'db0') -and ($_.SubKey -eq 'keys') } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Value"` ?

Comment: It seems that $results = (Get-RedisInfo -InfoType Keyspace | where {$_.Key -eq "db0"}).Value is returning a tuple: (keys, 299354) (expires, 299351) (avg_ttl, 6609766). What I need is just the first tuple value (299354). Any suggestions for how to extract just that? I tried $results.keys as well as $results.Item1